# Hot to reuse table header sort feature of Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

Is possible to reuse the table header sort feature of the admin forms in my own views and templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not re-use of the admin's feature, but you can use http://github.com/directeur/django-sorting for the same effect. It's ridiculously easy to implement in your own projects.

Use it together with http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/ though either can be used independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Why to reuse the sorting of django-admin.Sorting  is very easy in case of queryset.I simply used a get request and pass the col value and order of ording like **o=1&ord=asc**.In my view i made a dictionary which gives me the column value .THe queryset output has a order_by method.